# ImportError: No module named geocoders

Tags: python, geolocation

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module> 
    from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim    
  File "geopy.py", line 1, in <module>

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
```

Why am I getting this error? And `import geocoder` works fine.

Comment: @DavidG I don't agree with You. This is not code. Stacktarce looks better as blockquote, but the taste is not discussed.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup: I don't agree with you. Yeah it's not code, but it's `Traceback`. If you format a full Traceback use code format then it's more readable than `>`. But if it's just one-line error message (like the title), `>` sometimes is also fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename Your `geopy.py` file. This file overwrite the `geopy` package.